# Android margin popup drodown spinner

Tags: android, user-interface, drop-down-menu, spinner, dropdown

I would like something like that :

[image: wantedSituation]

but I have this result for now :
[image: CurrentSituation]

Indeed there is 1 problem, I want to apply a margin top de dropdown popup.
I tried 1 thing for that which didn't work :
popupTheme
There is my spinner :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:popupBackground="@color/bgChoicesSpinner"
                android:popupTheme="@style/popupOverlay"
                android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/spinnerCountry"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp">
```

There is my style :

```
<style name="popupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/bgChoicesSpinner</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `android:dropDownVerticalOffset="xxdp"` attribute.

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="40dp"
        ...
        />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make your spinner width like below image. For this you need to take one parent view and put spinner and drop down arrow on that parent view. Make sure your spinner width for achieve your actual image view.

[image]